# Manual Cloning of a mutli partition gpt disk to smaller target

Tags: partitioning, ssd, gpt, cloning

Ok so I have a Asus Laptop that came with 2x 128 GB ssd and its setup as a raid 0 totaling 256 GB. The first 4 partitions are the important ones.

I assembled the raid with mdadm and cloned the entire thing with dd to a file as a backup.
My plan is to break the raid after the clone is done, and dd back the first 4 partitions onto the first 128 GB disk, and resize the 4th OS partition to take up the remaining space.

My exact question is how do I handle the gpt partition table with gdisk? Do I need to worry about that at all?

> Model: Linux device-mapper (striped) (dm) Disk
>   /dev/mapper/isw_ccjcaiibej_ASUS_OS: 256GB Sector size
>   (logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition Table: gpt
>
> ```
> Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
>  1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot
>  2      106MB   1050MB  944MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
>  3      1050MB  1184MB  134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
>  4      1184MB  104GB   102GB   ntfs         Basic data partition (OS)
>  5      104GB   235GB   131GB   ntfs         Basic data partition (Data1)
>  6      235GB   256GB   21.5GB  ntfs         Basic data partition (Data2) hidden,diag
> ```

Comment: I could suggest Clonezilla, perhaps it has features you need http://clonezilla.org/ , http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php , and http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you copy back, gdisk will notice the disk is shorter and missing gpt metadata at the end.  To repair this, you can use either sequence: `v r d w` or `v x e w`.

`v`: verify disk (but not necessarily repair)

`r`: enter recovery and transformation menu

`d` (in the `r` menu): rebuild the backup gpt header

`x`: enter "expert" menu

`e` (int the `x` menu): move backup gpt structures to end of disk

`w` (in all menus): write to disk

https://linux.die.net/man/8/gdisk

Comment: So dd it back, restore the gpt from backup and then run gdisk on the drive and one of those sequences?

Comment: Just dd back and run gdisk. The gpt is part of the data you're copying.

Comment: I just needed to do the same and "v r d w" basically works, but you also need to remove partitions. I had partitions 7 and 8 spanning beyond the end of new disk.  Gdisk refused to write secondary partition table with following error : "Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by 1953498225 blocks! You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility. Aborting write operation! ..."  The solution is to remove surplus partitions by gdisk in advance and then repair : `d 8 d 7 v r d w y`  (last y means yes). (I have not tried v x e w)